# Convert Mysql Dump File from INSERT to INSERT IGNORE

Tags: insert, mysql

I have a huge dump file about 40G in size, and I need to dump that back into the database since there are some records are missing after a recovery.
Is there any easy way I can covert the INSERT into INSERT IGNORE in the dump file to avoid duplicate entries errors? loading the file to a text editor seems a no go to me.
thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your using a unix-like operating system, you can use `sed`:

```
cat file.sql | sed s/"^INSERT"/"INSERT IGNORE"/g > updated.sql
```

Comment: --insert-ignore option in mysqldump (as the answer bellow) is the best option. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore

Comment: @Happy while insert-ignore is a good option, the large majority of the people coming here are fully aware of that. But making a new dump is often not an option. 
There is no downside at using sed . Though the usage of quotation in the sample is strange. just put the entire sed statement into " "

Answer (score 60):

There is also a switch for mysqldump

--insert-ignore in mysqldump

Answer (score 0):

Use a text processing application like `sed` from the command line to do the search-replace on your imports.